# Android: the position of bottom navigation bar is at the center after generating the textview programatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have generated some textviews and programaticaly added to a linearLayout   but the position of bottom navigation bar is under the textview, not at the bottom. How can I fix the position of the bottom navigation bar?

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.datalayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    params.setMargins(20, 10, 10, 10);
TextView Temp=new TextView(getActivity());
Temp.setText("Temperature: "+temp);
 Temp.setLayoutParams(params);
 linearLayout.addView(Temp,0);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment=null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.number:
                    fragment=new data();
                    break;
                case R.id.graph:
                    fragment=new graph();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_drawer, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the code for the fragment page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/datalayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout as parent layout.
**For example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.palidroe.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/datalayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a view at the bottom it has to be explicitly be set in xml in the position you would like it to be.

You can have a container view above the BottomNavigation view and create your textviews inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a RelativeLayout, you can add a `Space` to your LinearLayout. A `Space` is a simple, invisible view made specifically for purposes like this. Give it a `layout_height` of `0dp` and a `layout_weight` of `1`, and it'll make sure any view below it sticks to the bottom of the layout.

Here's an example, based on your provided code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/datalayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```